# Excel formatting for different data types

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a set of data in CSV that needs quote marks around it. I can import it into Excel and apply the different formatting i.e \"@\", \"#\" and \"dd/mm/yy\" . Is there any way outside of vba to do this in one formatting code for text numbers and dates?

Comment: tried `TEXT()`?

Comment: I get what you mean, but I'll still have the same problem. For example, one column has phone numbers in and due to poor input controls, some have spaces in the middle, and so are text, and some don't and import as numbers. So it would need an if condition to fix. To compound the problem, the dates are saved in number format. Thanks anyway.

Comment: " some have spaces in the middle" > `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")` | "are text, and some don't and import as numbers" > `=NUMBERVALUE(A1)` | "dates are saved in number format" > (propose use of) '=DATEVALUE()` | Mind sharing some sample data (and the tested formula) to work with?

Comment: imho, a complex problem is almost always built from multiple simple problem that can be tackled 1 by 1.. without those detail (just the general overview) the maximum that any web viewer  can share is a general answer.

Comment: Yeah, they'll all make sense, but will take longer than just putting the formatting on. It will be done by someone with little to no Excel skill so. Adding formatting using filters takes about 3 minutes for them to do once I explained filters to them. Thanks for your help anyway.